# Why is $f(x,y)$ continuous if $\lim_{r\to 0}\sin\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)$ is not defined

Tags: continuity

I am currently studying with notes that our professor gave us and there we have to check if a function is continous:
Now let $f(x,y) = 0$ for $(x,y) = (0,0)$, $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|xy|}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)$ for $(x,y) \neq(0,0)$. 
We learned that you could transform $x$ and $y$ into polar coordinates and if $\lim_{r\to 0} \sqrt{|r^2|}\sqrt{|(\cos(\varphi)(\sin(\varphi)|}\sin\left(\frac{1}{(r(cos(\varphi))^2+(r(\sin(\varphi))^2}\right)$ = 0 and then it differentiable in from all sides and thus continuous.

Now my professor wrote that $\lim_{r\to 0} r\sqrt{|(\cos(\varphi)(\sin(\varphi)|}\sin(\frac{1}{r^2})$ = 0 since  $\lim_{r\to 0} \sqrt{|(\cos(\varphi)(\sin(\varphi)|}\sin(\frac{1}{r^2})$ is bounded but this does not make any sense in my eyes since $\sin\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)$ is not defined and thus can't be bounded... Where did I make my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Why can't $\sin\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)$ can't be bounded?  What is treason for the limit's failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every real number $x$, $\sin(x)\in[-1,1]$. Therefore$$(\forall r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}):\sin\left(\frac1{r^2}\right)\in[-1,1]$$and so, yes, your professor is right.

Comment: But $\lim_{x\to 0} sin(1/x^2) = \lim_{x\to \infty} sin(x^2) $ and this isn't defined for the same reason that $\lim_{x\to 0} sin(1/x) = lim_{x\to \infty} sin(x)$ is not defined?

Comment: @James That doesn't change the fact that you wrote that “since $\sin\left(\frac1{r^2}\right)$ is not defined and thus can't be bounded…” My answer proves that that claim is wrong. Anyway, since *both* $\sqrt{|\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)|}$ and $\sin\left(\frac1{r^2}\right)$ are bounded, it is indeed true that$$\lim_{r\to0}r\sqrt{|\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)|}\sin\left(\frac1{r^2}\right)=0.$$

Comment: Ok and even if its not defined it is still in the Intervall [-1,1]. Thank you

Comment: @James I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $|\sin \theta| \le 1$ and therefore

$$0\le \left|\sqrt{|xy|} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)\right|\le \sqrt{|xy|}\to 0$$